# Python -- Ancient Taxation

Tags: python, for-loop

In this problem it says that the first 10,000 drachs are not taxed, the next 20,000 are taxed 10%, the next 40,000 are taxed 20%, and any after the first 70,000 are taxed 30%. I'm fairly new to python, but this is what i have so far. I'm not sure where i've gone wrong. I think it is because i haven't defined the "tax" variable, but i'm not sure. any help would be much appreciated. THANKS!

**The code must also be terminated if the user enters in a negative number and i'm not sure how to add this to my for loops.

```
def income(drach):

    for drach in range(10000):
        tax = 0
    for drach in range(10000 , 30000):
        tax = ((drach - 10000)*0.1)
    for drach in range(30000 , 70000):
        tax = ((drach - 30000)*0.2) + 2000
    for drach in range(70000 , 10**999):
        tax = ((drach - 70000)*0.3) + 10000

    print tax
```

Comment: +1 just for the question title.

Comment: Do you have any sample runs? I have another idea of what the question implies.

Comment: If you replace the `for`s with `if`s, this works

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the correct taxation schema:

```
   def tax(income):
        tax=0;
        if income > 70000 : 
            tax += (income-70000)* 0.3 
            income = 70000
        if income > 30000 : 
            tax += (income-30000)* 0.2
            income = 30000
        if income > 10000 : 
            tax += (income-10000)* 0.1
        return tax;
```

Comment: I think you've missed decreasing the `income` value. Shouldn't this be 30% for the 70001th drahm and following, 20% for `[30001, 70000]` drahm and 10% for `[10001, 30000]` drahms? I.e. 160000 drahms would be taxed: 30% for `160000-70000=90000` drahms, 20% for `70000-30000=40000` drahms, 10% for `30000-10000=20000` drahms totalling `27000 + 8000 + 2000 = 37000` drahms of tax.

Comment: @kroolik it is working as expected by me and also you. Please check the code again. I run your example and result is the same.

Comment: @kroolik: He does decrease the income value, e.g. `income = 70000` at the end of the first `if` block.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths, yes, sorry - I've missed it. Guess I'm getting blind as a bat.

Answer (score 2):

You most likely don't want to use `for in` construct. In a `for x in iterable` construct, you loop through `iterable` assigning `x` to the next element *yielded* by `iterable`, until you reach the end (i.e. a [StopIteration](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) is raised).

Instead, you probably want to preserve the parameter `drach` and apply it to the taxation conditions.

As [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19120775/python-ancient-taxation/19120896#comment28274420_19120896) pointed out:

> The check drach in range(10000 , 30000) is very inefficient in Python 2. Better use 10000 <= drach < 30000.

So:

```
def income(drach):
    tax = 0
    if 10000 <= drach <= 30000:
        tax += ((drach - 10000)*0.1)
    if 30000 <= drach <= 70000:
        tax += ((drach - 30000)*0.2) + 2000
    if drach > 70000:
        tax += ((drach - 70000)*0.3) + 10000

    return tax
```

As an alternative you could loop through the slices:

```
def income(drach):
    tax = 0
    percent = step = 0.1
    lower = 10000
    for upper in [30000, 70000]:
        if lower < drach <= upper:
            tax += (drach - lower) * percent
        lower = upper
        percentage += step
    if lower < drach:
        tax += (drach - lower) * percent
    return tax
```

Comment: better return it rather than printing it.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı indeed, I just copy-pasted the OP and missed that. Thanks!

Comment: The check `drach in range(10000 , 30000)` is very inefficient in Python 2.  Better user `10000 <= drach < 30000`.

Comment: This won't work, if `drach > 70000` for instance, you'll only get taxed on the amount over 70,000, the 10% and 20% tax bands won't be calculated.

Comment: Why three separate if-statements?  Wouldn't an if/else-if/else block be more efficient?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I didn't check the math, but I believe that's what the +2000/+10000 are for: the amount of tax below 30,000/70,000 respectively

Comment: @thumbtackthief: You're right, didn't pay close enough attention to the addition.

Comment: rather than using magic numbers of 2000 and 10000, you can calculate with a trap based approach, check my solution.

Comment: @SeçkinSavaşçı indeed, I like your solution and Sven Marnach's the best.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `for` is used for looping over iterables.  For example

```
for drach in range(10000):
    tax = 0
```

assigns every value in the range 0, 1, 2, ..., 9998, 9999 to `drach`, and executes `tax = 0` for each of these.  This almost certainly isn't what you want -- you probably want `if` instead of `for`.

You could use the `max()` function to avoid using `if` as well:

```
tax = max(drach - 10000, 0) * 0.1 + 
      max(drach - 30000, 0) * 0.1 +
      max(drach - 70000, 0) * 0.1
```

Comment: +1 it's quite pythonic. Just one thing: shouldn't the coefficients be 0.3, 0.2, 0.1 instead of 0.1, 0.1, 0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the negative number bit -

```
if drach < 0:
    break
```

Will terminate the for loop when drach is negative. For more about this see more about [Python's Flow Control tools.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) You should be doing this when you get user input. Not when you are calculating the users tax.

Regarding calculating the taxes, you won't want to do for loops over a range of `drachs`. That is way more computation than you need.

You need to calculate what is called a [Progressive Tax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_tax).

Here is my data structure and associated function for calculating the progressive tax. **EDIT** - Made some mistakes with my function. It should be correct now.

```
tax_bracket = (
       #(from, to, percentage)
        (0,     10000, None),
        (10000, 30000, .10),
        (30000, 70000, .20),
        (70000, None,  .30),
        )


def calc_tax(drach):
    tax = 0

    for bracket in tax_bracket:
        # If there is no tax rate for this bracket, move on
        if not bracket[2]:
            continue

        # Check if we belong in this bracket
        if drach < bracket[0]:
            break

        # Last bracket
        if not bracket[1]:
            tax += ( drach - bracket[0] ) * bracket[2]
            break

        if drach >= bracket[0] and drach >= bracket[1]:
            tax += ( bracket[1] - bracket[0] ) * bracket[2]
        elif drach >= bracket[0] and drach <= bracket[1]:
            tax += ( drach - bracket[0] ) * bracket[2]
        else:
            print "Error"

    return tax



income = 50000

tax = calc_tax(income)
print tax
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using bisect:

```
from bisect import bisect
def income(drach):
    tax_brackets = [10000, 30000, 70000]
    rates = [lambda i: 0.0,
             lambda i: (i - 10000) * 0.1,
             lambda i: (i - 30000) * 0.2 + 2000,
             lambda i: (i - 70000) * 0.3 + 10000]
    return rates[bisect(tax_brackets, drach)](drach) if drach > 0 else None

>>> income(10000)
0.0
>>> income(15000)
500.0
>>> income(34400)
2880.0
>>> income(-15000)
None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly more general solution, to use with any provided set of tax brackets:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

'''Calculates income taxes.'''


def tax_on_bracket(income, lower, higher, rate):

    '''Calculates income taxes for a specified bracket.

    Setting the higher bound to 0 signifies no upper bound.'''

    if income <= lower:
        return 0
    elif income >= higher and higher != 0:
        return (higher - lower) * rate
    else:
        return (income - lower) * rate


def tax(income, brackets):

    '''Calculates income taxes based on provided income and tax brackets.'''

    total_tax = 0
    for (lower, higher, rate) in brackets:
        total_tax += tax_on_bracket(income, lower, higher, rate)

    return total_tax


def main():

    '''Main function.'''

    brackets = [(0, 10000, 0),
                (10000, 30000, 0.1),
                (30000, 70000, 0.2),
                (70000, 0, 0.3)]

    print('Tax for 9000 drach: {0}'.format(tax(9000, brackets)))
    print('Tax for 18000 drach: {0}'.format(tax(18000, brackets)))
    print('Tax for 27000 drach: {0}'.format(tax(27000, brackets)))
    print('Tax for 55000 drach: {0}'.format(tax(55000, brackets)))
    print('Tax for 90000 drach: {0}'.format(tax(90000, brackets)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```